# How can I determine most easily the keysyms of unusual keys on my keyboard, in Ruby, with Tk?

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit, keyboard-events

I'm using Ruby and Tk. I want to know the keysyms of various odd keys on my unusual keyboard. I want to know what they really are, not merely what some reference (such as
[this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/keysyms.htm))
says they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me using Ruby 2.2.5 (with Tk 8.5.12) on Windows 7:

```rb
# coding: utf-8

require 'tk'

def lambda_keypress
  @lambda_keypress ||= Kernel.lambda do |key_code, key_symbol|
    puts "lambda_keypress invoked with keycode #{key_code} and keysym #{key_symbol}."
  end
end

def root
  $root ||= begin
    Tk::Encoding.encoding = ''.encoding
    TkRoot.new
  end
end

root.bind :KeyPress, lambda_keypress, '%k %K'
Tk.mainloop
```